# Powershell script not passing csv as variable

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to script with powershell but some some reason the variables are not passed in the New- commands.

I get errors like : New-NAVServerUser DynamicsNav110 -WindowsAccount "$Username" -com ...

What am I missing ??

```
$csv = import-csv 'C:\Temp\user_list.csv' 
$csv | ForEach-Object {
    $Username = $_.Username
    $ProfileId = $_.ProfileId
    $LanguageId = $_.LanguageId
    $PermissionSetId = $_.PermissionSetId
    $Company = $_.Company
    New-NAVServerUser DynamicsNav110 -WindowsAccount "$Username" -company "$Company" -ProfileId "$ProfileId" -LanguageId "$LanguageId"
    New-NAVServerUserPermissionSet DynamicsNav110 -WindowsAccount "$Username" -PermissionSetId "$PermissionSetId"
}
```

Comment: Can you please post the full extent of the error message?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$csv = import-csv 'C:\Temp\user_list.csv' 
ForEach ($object in $csv) {
$object # This is just for troubleshooting. Use pause and then debug if needed.
New-NAVServerUser DynamicsNav110 -WindowsAccount "$object.Username" -company "$object.Company" -ProfileId "$object.ProfileId" -LanguageId "$object.LanguageId"
New-NAVServerUserPermissionSet DynamicsNav110 -WindowsAccount "$object.Username" -PermissionSetId "$object.PermissionSetId"
}
```

Slightly different 'ForEach' loop. Instead of piping a variable:

$Object can be renamed to anything.

We are literally just saying for each item in this list, do these things. We then use the $object.value to represent your column headers.